# pass an optional image UIImageView to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, segue, sdwebimage

I apologize because I already asked the same questions in another thread.

Thanks to a http call,I am able to fetch the url link to an image from the wikimedia API. So far I am unable to pass and display it in another view controller. I use the dependency 'SDWebImage' to display a url link.

here is the code for the http request

```
        let parameters : [String:String] = [
               "format" : "json",
               "action" : "query",
               "prop" : "extracts|pageimages",
               "exintro" : "",
               "explaintext" : "",
               "titles" : termDefinition,
               "indexpageids" : "",
               "redirects" : "1",
               "pithumbsize" : "500"
               ]

          //
          request(wikipediaURl, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
              if response.result.isSuccess {
                //1. on affiche le tableau json initial
                let definitionJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
                print(definitionJSON)

                // 3 valeurs : pageID,definition et source de l'image
                let pageId = definitionJSON["query"]["pageids"][0].stringValue
                let pageDefinition = definitionJSON["query"]["pages"][pageId]["extract"].stringValue

                let imageSource = definitionJSON["query"]["pages"][pageId]["thumbnail"]["source"].stringValue
                //on attache ces valeurs extraites aux bonnes variables
                self.illustration.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageSource))
                self.termDefinitionInfo = pageDefinition
                print(imageSource)



                // cas ou on n'a pas de definition
                if pageDefinition == "" {
                    self.termDefinitionInfo =  "Désolé,ce que vous cherchez ne se trouve pas sur Wikipedia"
                }

                // et on effectue le segue vers le second view controller ici
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDefinition", sender: self)
                print(self.termDefinitionInfo)

              } else {
                print("Error! Could not fetch data!")
            }
          }
      }
```

The image is located in the variable 'imageSource'. In the destination view controller, there is a UIImageView where I wish to display this. Here is the code in the destination view controller

```
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import SDWebImage

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var definitionIllustrationImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionTextView: UITextView!


    // on cree deux variables pour attacher l'image illustrative et la definition

    var definition: String?
    var imageIllustrative: UIImageView?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        definitionTextView.text = definition

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `prepareForSegue` and get the destination view controller, from there you can set your desired view controllers properties

If you want to pass an image yo could do this:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toDefinition",
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
            destinationViewController.imageFromWeb = imageFromWeb
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try this : I am able to pass some text and display it in a text view. however, whenever I try to pass an image, nothing is displayed. I am not good enough at using breakpoints to detect where my code is failing.

Comment: I finally ended up using a library : SDWebImage. it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution which works only because the image itself is displayed thanks to a library (SDWebImage).

However, I was able to pass the url data to the destination VC.

First you create a variable that will hold the value of the URL:
`var lienOriginalImage: String = ""`

In the http request, you pass the url to that variable :
`self.lienOriginalImage = imageSource`

in the destination view controller, create an optional string :
`var urlImage: String?`

Finally, in the prepare for segue, you can pass the data like so:
`secondVC.urlImage = lienOriginalImage`